# How can I draw a Rectangle in Android, of a given size, that positions itself in the view to which it is added?

Tags: android, layout, graphics, shapedrawable

I understand how to draw I shape, I am extending the `View` class, and overriding the `onDraw`, where I create a new `ShapeDrawbale` (Rectangle), which I then draw to the canvas:

```
    Rect rect = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    shapeDrawable.setBounds(rect);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().set(paint);
    shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

I then want to add this to a view defined in my Activities layout xml.
I do this by getting a handle on the view and calling:

```
innerLinear.addView(rectView); // where rectView is my custom class that extends View
```

My problem is that when creating the Rectangle, you have to provide `X` and `Y` coordinates.

So - how do I get the rectanlge positioned correctly within the `innerLayout`?

Do I have use the bounds of `innerLayout` to create the rectangle?  If so, when I call `innerLayout.getLeft()`, or `innerLayout.getTop()` etc.. 0 is always returned (I presume layout has not yet fully completed), so how do I do this?

Is there another way?
I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the `onDraw` method you can use following apis:

For x and y, the reference point is 0,0 with respect to parent view.

```
getWidth() // This is in View
getHeight() // This is in View
```

When you call above apis in your `CustomView` you will get the right dimensions of the parent view which in your case is `innerLayout`. Now if I have to cover all the area I ll write something like:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

This will fill your `CustomView` completely. How your 0, 0 is mapped to the actual screen coordinates, you dont worry about it. As I mentioned, your view's reference point is 0,0. And Android will calculate the actual screen coordinates.

For further ref:

[Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

[How Android draws](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)